# Getting an error "(subscript) logical subscript too long" while training SVM from e1071 package in R

Tags: r, svm

I am training svm using my traindata. (e1071 package in R). Following is the information about my data.

```
> str(train)
'data.frame':   891 obs. of  10 variables:
$ survived: int  0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
$ pclass  : int  3 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 ...
$ name    : Factor w/ 15 levels "capt","col","countess",..: 12 13 9 13 12 12 12 8 13 13 
$ sex     : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
$ age     : num  22 38 26 35 35 ...
$ ticket  : Factor w/ 533 levels "110152","110413",..: 516 522 531 50 473 276 86 396 
$ fare    : num  7.25 71.28 7.92 53.1 8.05 ...
$ cabin   : Factor w/ 9 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 9 3 9 3 9 9 5 9 9 9 ...
$ embarked: Factor w/ 4 levels "","C","Q","S": 4 2 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 2 ...
$ family  : int  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 4 2 1 ...
```

I train it as the following.

```
library(e1071)
model1 <- svm(survived~.,data=train, type="C-classification")
```

No problem here. But when I predict as:

```
pred <- predict(model1,test)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in newdata[, object$scaled, drop = FALSE] : 
(subscript) logical subscript too long
```

I also tried removing "ticket" predictor from both train and test data. But still same error. What is the problem?

Comment: Hard to answer without a reproducible example.  The error say that your newdata(test here) don't contain enough columns.

Answer (score 23):

There might a difference in the number of levels in one of the factors in 'test' dataset.

run str(test) and check that the factor variables have the same levels as corresponding variables in the 'train' dataset.

ie the example below shows **my.test$foo** only has 4 levels.....

```
str(my.train)
'data.frame':   554 obs. of  7 variables:
 ....
 $ foo: Factor w/ 5 levels "C","Q","S","X","Z": 2 2 4 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...

str(my.test)
'data.frame':   200 obs. of  7 variables:
 ...
 $ foo: Factor w/ 4 levels "C","Q","S","X": 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

Comment: changed the levels with data = factor(data, levels = c(std levels)). And it worked fine

Answer (score 3):

Thats correct train data contains 2 blanks for embarked because of this there is one extra categorical value for blanks and you are getting this error

$ Embarked   : Factor w/ 4 levels "","C","Q","S": 4 2 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 2 ...

The first is blank

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem today. It turned out that the `svm` model in `e1071` package can only use rows as the objects, which means one row is one sample, rather than column. If you use column as the sample and row as the variable, this error will occur.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your data is good (no new levels in test data), and you just need a small trick, then you are fine with prediction.

```
test.df = rbind(train.df[1,],test.df)
test.df = test.df[-1,]
```

This trick was from [R Random Forest - type of predictors in new data do not match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38097360/9037590).
Today I encountered this problem, used above trick and then solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing with that data set as well. I know this was a long time ago, but one of the things you can do is explicitly include only the columns you feel will add to the model, like such:

```
fit <- svm(Survived~Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp + Parch + Fare + Embarked, data=train)
```

This eliminated the problem for me by eliminating columns that contribute nothing (like ticket number) which have no relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue that resolved my code was the fact I hard forgotten to make some of my independent variables factors.

Comment: Is it an answer for the question? Or just suggesting another issue?